# In NodeJS, how do I make database queries inside of a Promise?

Tags: node.js, promise, knex.js

NodeJS 6.9.3

What I previously had went like this:

An outer function called "get_user()":

```
return database_queries.get_user(user_name)
  .then(function(results_from_database) {
```

and that function then ran a database call, using Knex, and returned:

```
            var dbquery = Multiline.stripIndent(function () {/*
                                                              SELECT
                                                              u.id as profile_id,
                                                              'user' as type_of_profile

                                                              FROM
                                                              user_profile u

                                                              WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]||user_name||[[:>:]]"
                                                            */});

            dbquery = dbquery.replaceAll('||user_name||', user_name);

            return DB.knex.raw(dbquery).then(function(result1) {

                for(var index_of_results = 0; index_of_results < result1[0].length; index_of_results++) {

                    var document1 = result1[0][index_of_results];
                    array_of_maps_with_profile_type_and_profile_id[document1["type_of_profile"]].push(document1["profile_id"]); 

                }
```

When I did this, the database query ran, and got data, but this happened asynchronously, without the results ever being returned to the outer function. In other words, the outer function had completed long before the database queries had run.

So I tried to wrap the inner function in a Promise:

```
function get_user(user_name) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    resolve ()
        .then(function() {

            var dbquery = Multiline.stripIndent(function () {/*
                                                              SELECT
                                                              u.id as profile_id,
                                                              'user' as type_of_profile

                                                              FROM
                                                              user_profile u

                                                              WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]||user_name||[[:>:]]"
                                                            */});

            dbquery = dbquery.replaceAll('||user_name||', user_name);

            return DB.knex.raw(dbquery).then(function(result1) {

                for(var index_of_results = 0; index_of_results < result1[0].length; index_of_results++) {

                    var document1 = result1[0][index_of_results];
                    array_of_maps_with_profile_type_and_profile_id[document1["type_of_profile"]].push(document1["profile_id"]); 

                }
```

Now the database calls don't seem to ever be called. When they run, they appear in the logs, but now there are no database queries appearing in the logs. It would seem this inner function now returns a Promise, but the "resolve()" part of the Promise is never called.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `knex.raw` returns a promise, so you don't need to create `Promise` here.

Comment: Then the database queries run in the background, instead of being returned  to the function that called the database-function. The database-function is being called from a loop.

Comment: In node.js no `background`, this function is asynchronous. That means that it returns result not immediately.

Comment: @alexmac -- yes, I know. I'm not clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: @alexmac -- I'm expecting to catch the result in the .then() block of the calling code.

Comment: Just a random note `resolve()` does not return promise, so you shouldn't try to call `resolve().then(...)` you should start by learning the basics how promises works exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit simpler way to write essentially the same query:

```
function get_user(user_name) {
  const regex = `[[:<:]]${user_name}[[:>:]]`;
  return DB.knex('user_profile')
    .where(DB.knex.raw(`?? REGEXP ?`, ['name', regex]))
    .then(res => {
      // do what ever you like with returned rows here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to simplify that a bit.

Take a look at these example projects.

https://github.com/joicenunes/helloapp

https://github.com/joicenunes/exercicio02

https://github.com/joicenunes/exercicio03

https://github.com/joicenunes/exercicio-04

(there are more, but you can find the rest)

Also avoid "replaceAll" and use binding variables.

Finally, since you are using node 6.x, you can use a few es6 goodies (arrow functions, multi-line strings, classes, etc), make the language work for you.

Comment: What could be simpler? One function calls another function that makes some database calls and returns a result. If you see a way this can be simpler, then please let me know.